# What's the difference between the bolt_session cookie and the bolt_authtoken cookie?

Tags: bolt-cms

Why is there a need for both the bolt_session and bolt_authtoken cookies? Could you explain what the difference is?

Answer (score 0):

The bolt_session cookie is session specific and identifies you for the duration of the session.

The bolt_authtoken cookie is used to store a token for your identification in the bolt admin interface after you logged in (if you remove it you will be logged out).